# Бот не находит команду

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = discord.Client()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'worstaudio/best',
               'noplaylist': 'True', 'simulate': 'True', 'preferredquality': '192', 'preferredcodec': 'mp3', 'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio'}


class mod(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount: int):  # задаем функцию, т.е. название команды.
        messages = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)  # пурджим сообщения, +1 т.к. наше тоже удалится

    @commands.command() # эмбед в заметки о всех командах
    async def cmds(self, ctx):
        cmdsembed = discord.Embed(title='`                     Команды ботa                           `')
        cmdsembed.add_field(name="`        Smart commands           `", value=">>> `!profil` —  посмотреть профиль\n`!avatar` —  посмотреть аватар\n`!cmds` —  все команды бота", inline=True)
        cmdsembed.add_field(name="`        Music commands              `", value=">>> `!join` —  бот зайдет в войс\n`!leave` —  бот выйдет из войса", inline=True)
        await ctx.send(embed=cmdsembed)

    @commands.command()
    async def profil(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Профиль — {ctx.message.author}") # главный эмбед
        embed.add_field(name=">>> Статус: ", value="`Не определен`", inline=True)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)  # ава справа квадратная
        embed.add_field(name=">>> Баланс: ", value="`0`", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name=">>> Голосовой онлайн: ", value="`0 ч / 0 м`", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name=">>> Возлюбленный/ая: ", value="`нет`", inline=True)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command()
    async def avatar(self, ctx):
        avaembed = discord.Embed(title = f"Аватар — {ctx.message.author}")
        avaembed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        avaembed.add_field(name=f">>> @{ctx.message.author} ,", value=" ниже `Ваша` аватарка.", inline=True)
        avaembed.set_image(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=avaembed)


youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0'  # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)
        self.data = data
        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = ""

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]
        filename = data['title'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return filename


    @bot.command(name = 'play')
    async def play(self,ctx, url):
        if not ctx.message.author.name == "Rohan Krishna":
            await ctx.send('NOT AUTHORISED!')
            return
        try:
            server = ctx.message.guild
            voice_channel = server.voice_client

            async with ctx.typing():
                filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
                voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
            await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(filename))
        except:
            await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


    @bot.command(name = 'join')
    async def join(self,ctx):
        if not ctx.message.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("{} is not connected to a voice channel".format(ctx.message.author.name))
            return
        else:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()


    @bot.command(name='pause')
    async def pause(self,ctx):
        voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
        if voice_client.is_playing():
            await voice_client.pause()
        else:
            await ctx.send("The bot is not playing anything at the moment.")


    @bot.command(name='resume')
    async def resume(self,ctx):
        voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
        if voice_client.is_paused():
            await voice_client.resume()
        else:
            await ctx.send("The bot was not playing anything before this. Use play_song command")


    @bot.command(name='leave')
    async def leave(self,ctx):
        voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
        if voice_client.is_connected():
            await voice_client.disconnect()
        else:
            await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


    @bot.command(name='stop')
    async def stop(self,ctx):
        voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
        if voice_client.is_playing():
            await voice_client.stop()
        else:
            await ctx.send("The bot is not playing anything at the moment.")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(mod(bot=bot))
```

Такая проблема `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found`. Команды не видит от play. я думаю проблема в двух классах и табуляции. Помогите новичку пожалуйста.)))

Answer (score 1):

```
class Music(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

@commands.command(name = 'play')
async def play(self,ctx, url):
    if not ctx.message.author.name == "Rohan Krishna":
        await ctx.send('NOT AUTHORISED!')
        return
    try:
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client

        async with ctx.typing():
            filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
            voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
        await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(filename))
    except:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


    @commands.command(name = 'join')
    async def join(self,ctx):
        if not ctx.message.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("{} is not connected to a voice channel".format(ctx.message.author.name))
            return
        else:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
       await channel.connect()


    @commands.command(name='pause')
    async def pause(self,ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_playing():
        await voice_client.pause()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not playing anything at the moment.")


    @commands.command(name='resume')
    async def resume(self,ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_paused():
        await voice_client.resume()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot was not playing anything before this. Use play_song command")


    @commands.command(name='leave')
    async def leave(self,ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_connected():
        await voice_client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


    @commands.command(name='stop')
    async def stop(self,ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_playing():
        await voice_client.stop()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not playing anything at the moment.")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot=bot))
```

Это необходимо вставить после класса YTDLSource. Он не загружает команды, так как YTDLSource не является классом кога.